# How to visualize missing values patterns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, missing-data

I know there are packages for visualizing missing values like `missingno`. How can I visualize missing values patterns without additional packages using Pandas and Matplotlib? I expect something like the following image where missing data is white:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get what you need using matplot:

```
import pandas as pd
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20, 10)
df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Jhonny/Desktop/titanic.xlsx")
plt.imshow(df.isnull(), cmap='hot', aspect='auto')
plt.show()
```

*note: I used a subset of titanic data from kaggle.*

**result:**

Starting from index 0, this heatmap visualization immediately tells us how (and where) missing values are distributed.

[image]

I know, i'ts not so fancy right now.
Matplot takes more work to turn this raw graphic into something nicer.

But if you want something better and fast, i really suggest `seaborn`.

`Seaborn` is a Python data visualization library **based on matplotlib**. It provides a high-level interface for drawing attractive and informative statistical graphics.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(df.isnull(), cbar=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could use `plt.imshow(..., aspect='auto')` to allow for non-square cells?

Comment: Thanks @JohanC, i edited my answer. Now matplot image looks better.